# SQLite rawquery fails to match expected strings

Tags: android, database, sqlite, wildcard

I'm using this method for a simple db search.

```
public Cursor queryExpense(String createdDate, String createdTime, String category, String description, String amount) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE + " LIKE ? AND " + COLUMN_TIME + " LIKE ? AND " +
            COLUMN_CATEGORY + " LIKE ? AND " + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " LIKE ? AND " + COLUMN_AMOUNT + " LIKE ? ";
    String mDate = createdDate.length() > 0 ? "%" + createdDate + "%" : "%";
    String mTime = createdTime.length() > 0 ? "%"  + createdTime + "%" : "%";
    String mCategory = category.length() > 0 ? "%" + category + "%" : "%";
    String mDescription = description.length() > 0 ? "%"  + description + "%" : "%";
    String mAmount = amount.length() > 0 ? "%"  + amount + "%" : "%";

    Log.d("Parameters",mDate + "," + mTime + "," + mCategory + "," + mDescription + "," + mAmount);

    return db.rawQuery( query, new String[] { mDate, mTime, mCategory, mDescription, mAmount } );
}
}
```

When no values are passed (All fields are "%"), one of the results is this record:

```
Date: 30/10/2016
Time: 6:56:41
Category: Food
Description: Lunch at Nosh
Amount: 25
```

However the same record does NOT appear when specifying the description as "unc". The debug log shows the expected parameters and SQL, so i'm not sure why this is not a result.

```
SELECT * FROM expenses where createdDate like ? and createdTime like ? and category like ? and description like ? and amount like ?
[%,%,%,%unc%,%]
```

What am i missing?

**EDIT: Problem Solved**

Thanks to @laalto i've identified the problem to be due to having both Cursor.moveToFirst and Cursor.moveToNext, as a result of which the search may have been skipping the one result.

Comment: To me the code looks like you're really matching `unc%` and not `%unc%` since you're adding the `%` at the end only. Does not explain the debug output though.

Comment: Ah Im actually matching any substring.  I missed the leading % for each field in the code.  Edited now.

Comment: @laalto Weird thing is, some rows in the table are just fine when searching this way. It only appears to be an issue for certain rows although i'm not seeing any pattern.

Comment: FWIW, the first row inserted in the table does not show up in any results.

Comment: What are you doing with the cursor then? If you have both `moveToFirst()` and `moveToNext()` it'll skip the first row.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I'm an idiot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on question comments: The query is just fine and matches the expected row.

The problem is reading the returned `Cursor`. A construct like

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        //...
    }
}
```

skips the first result row, which is the only returned row with the more specific selection criteria.

Idiomatic pattern for iterating over cursors would be:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        //...
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.